# how to open new tab with command line in file explorer?

Tags: python, command-line, directory, windows-11, microsoft-file-explorer

I want to open a new folder in different tabs on the same window of Windows File Explorer in Windows 11, instead of opening a new window every time.

I tried to use
 `Start.exe C:\` `Explorer.exe C: \ -W 0` `Explorer.exe C: \ --windows 0` in terminal and Python.

```
import os
import sys
gpus = sys.argv[1]
path = os.path.realpath(gpus)
os.startfile(path)
```

but it always opens in a new window.

Comment: I'm not sure you can - it doesn't appear to be documented and users in the MS forums are saying it's not currently supported (like [here for example](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-22h2-explorerexe-command-line-switch-to/b0958474-6124-44c9-b01a-7e6952317848))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some research on your problem and concluded that it is not allowed to open Tabs in the file explorer.

In this link we can see that as of 11/09/2022 there is no response by MSFT

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-11/22h2-explorer-tabs-save-configuration/m-p/3672808